# Find all vectors y such that Ax = y is inconsistent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, systems-of-equations

I am given a matrix A, but that is it. The question is to find all vectors y such that Ax = y is inconsistent, where x is a vector as well (no values are given).

My first thought is that there is an infinite number of y vectors that make this inconsistent, is that not true?

Comment: It depends on $A$. If $A$ is invertible then $x=A^{-1}y$ is a solution for any $y$. But e.g. if $A=0$ then $Ax=y$ is only consistent if $y=0$.

Comment: By expanding the matrix multiplication, you can show that $Ax$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ (viewed as column vectors), with coefficients given by the components of $x$. This means $y=Ax$ is possible if and only if $y$ is in the span of the columns of $A$.